# FancyBox 3.5.7 not showing up on WordPress - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to implement FancyBox 3.5.7 on my WordPress site: https://softcroco.com/download-shareit-apk/ (Example page). However, it doesn't show up as shown in the following site:

https://techylist.com/lucky-patcher-apk-download/#group-1

Steps done so far:

1. I downloaded FancyBox 3.5.7from the following link: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/releases/tag/v3.5.7
2. I uploaded the FancyBox files after extraction to /wp-content/themes/my-theme/fancybox.
3. I pasted the following code inside my themefunction.php

```js
    function enqueue_fancybox_scripts() {
    // Register and enqueue FancyBox CSS
    wp_register_style('fancybox-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css', array(), '3.5.7');
    wp_enqueue_style('fancybox-css');

    // Register and enqueue FancyBox JS
    wp_register_script('fancybox-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.5.7', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('fancybox-js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_fancybox_scripts');
```

And that's it the FancyBox doesn't work when I click on my post images!

Any help appreciated.

A lot of copy and past and code manipulation but nothing happens!